# access parameter passed by symfony 2.7 on the template

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to access an array that I passed via the $this-render('url', array) on the the template. I'm following the Symfony book where I got this example, I just can't get it to work.

My Controller

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController extends Controller{

/**
 * @Route("lucky/number/{count}")
 */
public function numberActionTemplate($count){
    $numbers = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $numbers[] = rand(0, 100);
    }

    $results = implode(',', $numbers);

    $numbers = array(0=>'b', 1=>'a', 2=>'c');

    return $this->render('lucky/number.html.php', array('luckyNumberList' => $numbers));
}
```

My template

> ```
> <html>
>  <head>
>  <h1>Testing</h1>
>  </head>
>  <body>
>  <ul>
>     <li>
>         <?php $luckyNumberList[0] ?>
>     </li>
>  </ul>
>  </body>
>  </html>
> ```

At this point im not sure what I'm doing wrong. Basic php experience and started with symfony a few days ago.

Comment: Please share a link to the source of this code. Do you use Twig with PHP enabled? In the default configuration of Symfony, PHP is disabled in Twig templates.

Comment: @A.L I'm running it on my local computer. Thank you for pointing out that it is disabled by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symfony is using Twig templates, while you're trying to use PHP templates.

The normal way to write it is:

```
<li>
     {{ luckyNumberList[0] }}
</li>
```

You can look at the Twig reference:

http://symfony.com/en/doc/current/book/templating.html

Comment: Thank you Dric512. I did use a PHP template, after switching it to a twig file I was able to access the array.

Answer (score 1):

What code did you use? I searched `class LuckyController` and found this code from the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html#create-the-template):

```
{# app/Resources/views/lucky/number.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>Lucky Numbers: {{ luckyNumberList }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

It's important to note that there is no PHP in this Twig template.

If you want to display one value from your PHP Table, you can [access to any item from the array with Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables):

```
…
<h1>Lucky Numbers: {{ luckyNumberList[0] }}</h1>
…
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I did made the mistake in thinking I could access this with php aswel.

Comment: @Honto756K that's possible with a little configuration, see malcolm's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to use `echo`, nothing serious:

```
<?php echo $luckyNumberList[0] ?>
```

I suppose that you included `php` templating engine in configuration:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    templating:
        engines: ['php', 'twig']
```

Comment: Is it this simple to activate PHP in Twig? I thought it was more complicated.

Comment: Thank you malcolm for helping me out on that aswel.

Comment: @A.L I never used it, but looks so simple http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html